# Multi level vanity URLs in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, routes, eloquent

I have a system in place that takes `http://myurl.com/username` and loads the profile page for the given user. I also want to add in another layer that does the following :

1. URL entered is `http://myurl.com/username/somevanity`.
2. It should check if `username` exists in the `users` table
3. if yes, take the `id`, and check if it exists in the `user_id` field of the `homepage` table.
4. If present, it should check if `somevanity` exists in the `vanity_url` field.
5. If yes, it must load a page with a simple echo of `feed_url`

The redirection works fine, **but the `home` variable does not have the right data.**

This is my table structure :

```
Columns:
id int(10) UN AI PK 
user_id int(11) 
active varchar(1) 
title varchar(60) 
feed_url varchar(255) 
created_at timestamp 
updated_at timestamp 
vanity varchar(50)
```

And this is what I have tried so far :

```
Route::get('/{username}/{vanity}', function($username,$vanity)
    {
        $user = User::where('username', '=' , $username); //Check if user exists

    if($user->count()) 
    {
        $user = $user->first();
        $user = $user->id;
        $home = Homepage::where('user_id','=',$user)->where('vanity','=',$vanity)->get();

        if($home->count())
        {
            return View::make('homepage')->with('home',$home);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::to('landing')->withErrors('Homepage not found!');
        }   

    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::to('landing')->withErrors('Username not found!');
    }
    });
```

However, when I try to dump `$home` like this from `homepage.blade.php` -

```
 @if (Session::has('home'))
        {{ $site =  Session::get('home') }}
 @endif


<?php echo dd($site) ?>
```

I get only the following information that I am assuming is Eloquent's data -

```
   object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)[265]
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(Blog)[263]
          protected 'fillable' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected 'table' => string 'homepage' (length=8)
          protected 'connection' => null
          protected 'primaryKey' => string 'id' (length=2)
          protected 'perPage' => int 15
          public 'incrementing' => boolean true
          public 'timestamps' => boolean true
          protected 'attributes' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
          protected 'original' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
          protected 'relations' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'hidden' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'visible' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'appends' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'guarded' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'dates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'touches' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'observables' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          protected 'with' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          public 'exists' => boolean true
          protected 'softDelete' => boolean false
```

Comment: Add something constructive if you plan to downvote.

Comment: As I said, doesn't seem to work. The same problem you helped me with regarding the profile page, I attempted to implement it here again. Unfortunately the `$home` variable does not seem to have the right data..

Comment: I just need to echo the `feed_url` and `title` from the table

Comment: What does $home->user_id contain?

Comment: Gives me this error - `ErrorException Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$user_id (View: D:\mysite\app\views\homepage.blade.php)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `->get()` after the eloquent database query:

```
$home = Homepage::where('user_id','=',$user)->where('vanity','=',$vanity)->get();
```

Comment: Tried this as well, a majority of the errors vanished (Updated in question), but there is still no data

Comment: Also tried adding `->first()` too, still doesn't help

Comment: What errors? Have you tried to create a new session in case some old session variables are lingering?

Comment: Ah by errors I meant the invalid data. Originally it had a lot more statements from `Eloquent/Illuminate`. And yes I cleared all sessions before testing!

Comment: You seem to be getting a Collection and that seems correct. Can you access `$site->perPage` ?

Comment: I can see it in the dump data, but if I try to access it, I get `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$perPage`

Comment: This is how I see it in the dump - `protected 'perPage' => int 15`

Comment: Well of course. It's a collection of eloquent objects. If you do a foreach on $site you can access the properties of the objects.

Comment: Okay I tried that and finally managed to get some workable data! However when I pass the username that has an id of `10`, it instead shows me the data for username with an id of `12`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55504/discussion-between-hansn-and-sainath-krishnan).

Comment: Thanks for the help, @hansn ! :) Issue was using the `first()` tag which caused it to take the very first record from the table